# has_many relationship not working in a fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, fixtures

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Article Model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Article fixture:

```
one:
  url: http://www.google.com/
  title: Sample Title
  user: default
```

User fixture:

```
default:
  email: user@example.com
  name: Test User
```

Trying `Article.first.user` in a test case works fine, but if I try to get the opposite relationship working with the following in my User fixture:

```
default:
  email: user@example.com
  name: Test User
  articles: one
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "articles" of relation "users" does not exist
```

Comment: You dont need the `articles: one`. It should work automatically.

Comment: @SampritiPanda Can you put that in an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add another line in the users fixture to specify a lists of articles. All you need to do is specify the user in the article fixture (which sets the `user_id` column for the article) and Rails figures out the articles for a user using that foreign key.

So, your articles fixture should be:

```
default:
  email: user@example.com
  name: Test User
```